# Does PayPal have a shipping api?

Tags: php, api, paypal

We have an online marketplace and we only use paypal to checkout. 
We have a custom paypal chained payment setup integrated at the moment but after payment is made sellers do not have access to the buyers shipping information through paypal and can not print shipping labels through paypal either. 
Does Paypal offer a shipping API which we can integrate to allow sellers to print shipping labels and even gather tracking info when a transaction is completed using paypal? 
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Adaptive Payment, you can use the SetPaymentOptions API to get buyers shipping address.

Read it here : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/SetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/